# Understanding curve function in R

Tags: r, curve

I am new to R and trying to better understand how it works.

I don't understand why with function curve we don't need to write function(x), I mean for example with plot we need to write

```
 plot(function(x) pnorm(x,0,1),-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

but if we use curve we must just write

```
  curve(pnorm(x,0,1),-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

without function(x) before pnorm, why ?

My second question concerning curve is why

```
curve(x+0 ,-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

works fine but

```
curve(x,-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

returns an error

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
plot(function(x) pnorm(x,0,1),-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

you're actually calling `plot.function`. (Notice the difference of the arguments for `plot()` under `?plot` and `?plot.function`.) `plot.function` expects a function for its first argument, and `curve` expects an expression:

```
# expr: The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as
#       a function of ‘x’ which will evaluate to an object of the
#       same length as ‘x’.
```

For your second question, it would seem that `curve` recognizes `x+0` as an expression, but with just `x` alone it's looking for the object named `x` (hence the error). If you assign `x` to something like `x=5`, then

```
curve(x+0 ,-3.5,3.5,col='BLUE',n=1000)
```

will also return an error, since now for sure `x+0` is not an expression. The variable `x` in `curve` isn't necessarily special; you can change the variable to be whatever with the `xname` argument).